# How to compare the values of two dicts?

Tags: python

```
length = {(0,0):[1,3], (0,1):[1,3,5,7], (1,1):[2,4,7], (1,2):[3,1,6]}
threshold = {(0,0):2, (0,1):4, (1,1):6, (1,2):3}
```

How to compare each value of `length`'s arrays with `threshold`'s values?

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```py
length = {(0, 0): [1, 3], (0, 1): [1, 3, 5, 7], (1, 1): [2, 4, 7], (1, 2): [3, 1, 6]}
threshold = {(0, 0): 2, (0, 1): 4, (1, 1): 6, (1, 2): 3}

for k, v in length.items():
    for l in v:
        if l > threshold[k]:
            # do what you need...
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for key in length:
    for val in length[key]:
        # Compare val with threshold[key]
```

This code assumes that both `length` and `threshold` has the same keys. You can simply check if the key is in the dict:

```py
if key in threshold:
```